# .htaccess vanity url not redirecting properly

Tags: apache, web

I've got a blog subdirectory on my website (foo.com/blog), and I'm following a tutorial that offers a brief explanation of vanity urls.

Basically, I'm trying to get it so that when the user navigates to 'foo.com/blog/xyz' the 'xyz' variable (username) redirects the user to:

```
foo.com/blog/profile.php?username=xyz
```

but still displays as:

```
foo.com/blog/xyz
```

The code in the tutorial doesn't work, so I've been relying on code in the youtube comments under it:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.foo.com/blog/profile.php?username=$1 [NC]
```

The problem is, when I try to navigate to 'foo.com/blog/xyz' it instead redirects to:

```
foo.com/blog/profile.php?username=blog/xyz
```

So obviously the username is being set to blog/xyz instead of xyz itself.

Likewise, if navigate to foo.com/xyz, it redirects to where it is supposed to go:

```
http://www.foo.com/blog/profile.php?username=xyz
```

But displays this url as it is instead of showing up as foo.com/blog/xyz (like how reddit shows up as reddit.com/u/username for users)

So it appears I have two problems:

- **1)** I can't figure out how to make it so that it only does the rewrite when I navigate to foo.com/blog/xyz rather than foo.com/xyz (.htaccess is in public_html -- I tried moving it to public_html/blog but it didn't work)
- **2)** I can't figure out how to get it to display as blog/xyz instead of blog/profile?php?username=xyz

I don't know much about apache, and I really just need to get this one piece of code right so I can continue bashing my head against the wall with the rest of the tutorial. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you refer to the documentation of the tools you use instead of relying on some blog post or youtube video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you never mentioned in your rule set anything about how to treat that`/bog` part of the request path. *Do it...*

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?blog/(.*)$ /blog/profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

I also cleaned up a few other issues with the code you posted which would prevent it from working as you claim *at all*.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Code works, thanks! Unfortunately I'm suck with free hosting for now (only way to get my website accessible in China without getting scammed again) -- but I'll keep it in mind for the future.